# Copy Resource plist file to Application Support folder?

Tags: ios, plist, nsfilemanager

Is there any way to copy a plist file to the Application Support folder in iOS?.

The method below returns the Application Support foldery path, but I need to copy the resource plist file into that folder. Instead of using `CopyItemAtUrl` method and then delete from bundle.

```
- (NSURL*)applicationDataDirectory {

    NSFileManager* sharedFM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSArray* possibleURLs = [sharedFM URLsForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory
                                             inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
    NSURL* appSupportDir = nil;
    NSURL* appDirectory = nil;

    if ([possibleURLs count] >= 1) {
        // Use the first directory (if multiple are returned)
        appSupportDir = [possibleURLs objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // If a valid app support directory exists, add the
    // app's bundle ID to it to specify the final directory.

    if (appSupportDir) {
        NSString* appBundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
        appDirectory = [appSupportDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:appBundleID];
    }

    return appDirectory;
}
```

Comment: So to clarify, you want to copy a `.plist` file from the app bundle into the Application Support folder? What problems are you having doing this?

Comment: No.Can i manually drag file into application support?. Instead of coping the file from bundle to Application Folder and then delete the file from bundle.

Answer (score 1):

The framework returns the correct path to the Application Support folder but unlike the `Documents` folder it's not being created by default.

Use the alternative API of `NSFileManager` which is able to create the folder implicitly

```
- (NSURL*)applicationDataDirectory {

    NSFileManager* sharedFM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL* appSupportDir = [sharedFM URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
    // add the app's bundle ID to it to specify the final directory.

    NSString* appBundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    return [appSupportDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:appBundleID];
}
```

Be aware that you are responsible for creating the sub folder, too.

```
- (NSURL*)applicationDataDirectory {

    NSFileManager* sharedFM = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSURL* appSupportDir = [sharedFM URLForDirectory:NSApplicationSupportDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
    // add the app's bundle ID to it to specify the final directory.

    NSString* appBundleID = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier];
    NSURL* appDirectory = [appSupportDir URLByAppendingPathComponent:appBundleID];
    if (![appDirectory checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:nil]) {
        [sharedFM createDirectoryAtURL:appDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
    return appDirectory;
}
```